# UIButton shows tintColor only when being pressed, not in normal state

Tags: ios, objective-c, colors

Here's my code.  It creates a white button that turns purple on being pressed.  What I want is a purple button.

```
    if (!backButton) {
    backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [backButton setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    backButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:17];
    CGSize size = [aboutButton.titleLabel.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:23]];
    backButton.frame = CGRectMake(screenWidth/2 - size.width/2, screenHeight-size.height*4, size.width, size.height);
    backButton.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:123/255.0 green:47/255.0 blue:85/255.0 alpha:1]; //This is the color I want the button to be in its normal state.
    [backButton addTarget:self action:NSSelectorFromString(@"displaySettingsScreen") forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
[self.view addSubview:backButton];
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, the tintColor property doesn't work for RoundedRect button types.

See here:
[Why is my UIButton.tintColor not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066008/why-is-my-uibutton-tintcolor-not-working)

To get around this, I use a single-segment UISementedControl, in place of the UIButton I wanted colored.

This answer here describes the technique:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4971371/785411

Another alternative would be to use a purple image for the button - though that would require a bit more work.

Answer (score 1):

Rounded rect buttons are hard to change, so use a custom button instead, and set the background color:

```
if (!backButton) {
        backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [backButton setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        backButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:17];
        CGSize size = [aboutButton.titleLabel.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:23]];
        backButton.frame = CGRectMake(screenWidth/2 - size.width/2, screenHeight-size.height*4, size.width, size.height);
        backButton.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0f;
        backButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:123/255.0 green:47/255.0 blue:85/255.0 alpha:1]; //This is the color I want the button to be in its normal state.
        [backButton addTarget:self action:NSSelectorFromString(@"displaySettingsScreen") forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    [self.view addSubview:backButton];
```

You'll need to add the QuartzCore framework, and import it (for the layer properties to work).

Comment: Any reason you didn’t use `@selector(displaySettingsScreen)`? If you do, you get compile-time safety checks.

Comment: @ZevEisenberg, no reason, I just didn't think of that.